# Mapbox iOS Mutable RMPolylineAnnotation

Tags: ios, mapbox

I am wishing to use the RMPolylineAnnotation object to draw a path behind the user, I have this working presently, but I am currently creating a new RMPolylineAnnotation in didUpdateUserLocation, and this seems to cause issues with lag and jaggyness. It also does not seem to show the users' path when travelling in a downward direction on the map.

Here is the code in my didUpdateUserLocation Method:

```
CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[[[mapView userLocation] location] coordinate].latitude longitude:[[[mapView userLocation] location] coordinate].longitude];
    [locations addObject:location];

path = [[RMPolylineAnnotation alloc] initWithMapView:mapView points:locations];
[mapView addAnnotation:path];
```

Does anyone know of a better way to create this path, and avoid the lag and jaggedness?

Answer (score 0):

Are you removing the old annotation(s) each time you do this? That could be affecting performance.